# reading across the rows and columns

Tags: python

I have following text that I am able to read using my code

```
1;6;7.1023;13;7.4583;15;7.8140;45;6;7.1023;13;7.4583;15;7.8140;45
2;6;19.1023;13;19.4583;15;19.8140;45;6;19.1023;13;19.4583;15;19.8140;45
4;6;19.1023;13;19.4583;15;19.8140;45;6;19.1023;13;19.4583;15;19.8140;45
...
20; ...
```

I wrote following code:

```
my_val = []
row=20
col=15
fr = open("%s" %filename,"r")
for i in range(0,row):
  for j in range (0,col):
    a = fr.readline().split(";")
    my_val = my_val + [float(a[2])]
print my_val
```

This gives me values at location a[2] ( e.g. in first row: 7.1023) on every line from row 1 to 20.

What I want is to simultaneously capture the values a[2]..a[4],a[6] from every row for rows- row1,4..7 (i.e. every third row) and store it in my_val.

Any ideas how I can extend the above code to do this.

Comment: can you add output example? so it will be more clear what you want it to do

Comment: Done I have added the output

Comment: If you need only the float values in that input, the output you want is `a[2],a[4],a[6],a[9],a[11]` and not `a[2]..a[4],a[6]`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly what you want it to do, then I think this code will do it:

```
my_val = []
row=20
col=15

f = open("%s" %filename,"r")
lines = f.readlines()

for i in range(1,row,3):
    a = lines[i].split(";")
    for j in range(2,col,2):    
        my_val.append(float(a[j]))

print my_val

f.close()
```